# datetime not converting uppercase month abbrevations

Tags: pandas, datetime

I have 1.6 million rows of data and I need to calculate difference between two dates. I have read the data from an excel file and then looked for the dtypes of columns. The date and time columns both have object datatypes. I need to convert these columns into datetime. I have tried it but it is only working for time but not for date. I have tried the following:

```
test = pd.read_excel(datadir+'test.xlsx', sheetname = 'Sheet1' )
test['time'] =  pd.to_datetime(test['time'], format='%H:%M:%S')
test['date'] =  pd.to_datetime(test['date'], format='%d%b%y')
```

It does work for time but not for date and gives the following error: ValueError: unconverted data remains: 14

I have also tried without specifying format for date but then I get ValueError: Unknown string format

`print(len(test['date']))` returns 7
`print(test['date'].iloc[0])` returns 17JAN2014.

Here is the sample data:
date    time
17JAN2014   12:48
18JAN2014   13:15
17JAN2014   09:20
18JAN2014   07:45
04FEB2012   10:00
05FEB2012   17:22
12MAR2012   19:50

I have no clue what is going wrong. Any help will be appreciated. One more thing, Can anyone tells me how do I combine date and time columns into one column as a datetime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem with year, need `Y` for match `YYYY`, `y` match `YY`.
Check also http://strftime.org/.

```
df['date'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d%b%Y')
print (df)
        date   time
0 2014-01-17  12:48
1 2014-01-18  13:15
2 2014-01-17  09:20
3 2014-01-18  07:45
4 2012-02-04  10:00
5 2012-02-05  17:22
6 2012-03-12  19:50
```

Comment: thanks. putting %Y works perfect for the sample data. I just tried the same on the my final dataset having 1.6M rows, I got the following error:     OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 2999-12-31 00:00:00 . Do you understand what does it mean?

Comment: It means data are not valis,because [out of limits](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#timestamp-limitations). One possible solution is convert problematic dates to `NaT`s by `df['date'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d%b%Y', errors='coerce')`, Working with this data is [possible](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#representing-out-of-bounds-spans), but convert from strings is pain, I think apply is necessary.